# how to fetch ID from other site?

Tags: php

Just let me know how one site fetch Logged in ID of other site?
e.g. If i already logged-in in Gmail,then how any other site fetch gmail email ID into their user name textbox?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This would only be possible if Gmail had an API for it. You can't read an other domain's cookies, for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Such behavior is obtained via a common loggin system. On Gmail a lot other (like StackOverflow), they use [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID), some other uses [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) like Twitter.

But, I don't know if you're allowed to access user's data, like your their Gmail address. I've never used OpenID before.

Comment: If I develop a website in php and on its signup page I wanted logged-in user id only to be filled by default in User name text box?

Comment: You can't have it on the sign up, since the user hasn't authenticated yet. Also I'm not sure can have it even after they authenticated, it depends on what OpenID offers as API.